# Openxml C# while adding a new pragraph

Tags: c#, openxml

First I have created a paragraph in openxml

```
Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
try
{

    ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
    ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { 
                                                     Val = "Correspondence" };
    paragraphProperties1.AppendChild(paragraphStyleId1);
    Run run1 = new Run();
    Text text1 = new Text();
    text1.Text = array[1];
    run1.AppendChild(text1);
    paragraph1.AppendChild(paragraphProperties1);
    paragraph1.AppendChild(run1);
}
catch { }
```

After that i traverse my document paragraph by paragraph and add paragraph that i have described above.

```
var ps = wordDoc1.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Paragraph>();
bool addBool;
addBool = false;                        

foreach (Paragraph pg in ps)
{
    if (addBool == true)
    {                                
        //pg.Append(paragraph1);
        //wordDoc1.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
        break;
    }
    if (pg.InnerXml.Contains(@"w:val=""Author""") == true)
    {                                
        addBool = true;                                
        pg.Append(paragraph1);
        //pg.InnerXml = pg.InnerXml + array[0];
        wordDoc1.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
        break;

    }   
}
```

So, It will just append the paragraph into the select paragraph.

My Question:
How can i insert a new paragraph just below the selected paragraph?
Note** And it should not merge into the paragraph but is should create a new paragraph

Answer (score 0):

You can use pg.InsertAfter method to insert new paragraph. Doing so will automatically add paragraph breaks before and after the paragraph.